# How does type casting happens in Python between list and tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to debug a code and figured that we cant pass single float or int argument to tuple as follows:

```
tuple(5) 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

however `tuple([5])` works.

Does python converts int to list to tuple above? If so then why does this gives error as well?

```
tuple(list(5)) 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is your intent to produce a list containing a single 5, like `[5]`, or to produce a list of length 5?

Comment: My intent is to understand what is causing the error. If I add single number it throws an error tuple((5)). But tuple((5,5)) doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error comes about because `list(5)` is the part throwing the `TypeError`, for the same reason that `tuple(5)` throws the `TypeError`.

You can use

```
>>> tuple(list([5]))
(5,)
>>> tuple(list(5 for _ in range(1)))
(5,)
```

both work fine.

Comment: My concern is why tuple((5)) throws error and not tuple((5,5)). How come python assigns the iterator property to one and not other. Or is it something we simply accept and move on?

Comment: Because `(5)` is not a `tuple`, it's an `int`. You can check by doing `type((5))`. `type((5,))`, however, returns `tuple`, so we can do `tuple((5,))` just fine.

Comment: I see. Thats why tuple([5]) also works?

Comment: Exactly. The [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) constructor takes an iterable - so anything like a list, tuple or generator.

Comment: noted. so essentially adding a "comma" after the digit makes its iterable.

Comment: Yes, essentially. `(5,)` is a `tuple` with one thing in it - the `int` 5.